# How to make Attachments panel in Adobe Reader visible when opening PDF (using iTextSharp)?

Tags: itext

Is there a way I can use iTextSharp [addViewerPreference](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/interfaces/PdfViewerPreferences.html#addViewerPreference%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject%29) method, let say on Stamper or PdfWriter object, so that when opening the resulting PDF file in Adobe Reader, the Attachments panel will be visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ViewerPreferences:

```
pdfWriter.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageModeUseAttachments;
```